# If interstellar medium was dense plasma and light slowed down, would things appear to move slower far away?

Tags: light, speed, density, plasma-physics

Voyager 2 recently left the solar system and registered an increase in plasma density. If light moved slower in this dense plasma, would it appear like events in other solar systems played out slower than they actually do?

Comment: "dense" is a relative word here.  The interplanetary plasma is still a very very good vacuum, compared to most vacuums created on Earth.

Answer (score 2):

> If light moved slower in this dense plasma, would it appear like events in other solar systems played out slower than they actually do?

First, the [interstellar medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium) is not a "dense" [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) like the Sun's [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) (which is also extremely tenuous compared to, say, water).

Let's ignore that for now and assume the plasma density was high enough to change the [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) (thus, the [index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) too) such that electromagnetic waves moved at a speed well below the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) in vacuum.  This would not affect time, i.e., there would be no [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) due to this propagation speed difference.  The only difference is that it would take longer for the same electromagnetic wave to move through the dense plasma than a vacuum.